# D3D Failed to generate mipmap automatically on some cards!

Tags: direct3d, mipmaps

On most of computers my program performs fine. But on one computer it failed to generate mipmap.

I created a texture with D3DUSAGE_AUTOGENERATEMIPMAP,

D3DCAPS2_CANAUTOGENMIPMAP says yes and CheckDeviceFormat says D3D_OK(not D3DOK_NOAUTOGEN) too.

then I use LoadSurfaceFromMemory to fill the texture.

But on that particular computer, no mipmap is generated. What's worse, the computer is my leader's!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet its an intel (or other lesser manufacturer) integrated or that its drivers are not up-to-date.  If it works using the "reference" (REF) driver then its a driver bug.

If you are loading a surface from memory anyway is it really that much extra to call D3DXFilterTexture afterwards?  Its far more likely to work.

Alas you discover the joys of caps that outright lie :(

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried on my own computer..(I cannot access my leader's of course..) I Created a dynamic texture in default pool with mipmaps but do not autogen mapmap, I call D3DXFilterTexture to generate mipmaps. But it doesn't work. and it takes a lot of time. I think I just didn't go the right way. Although, I learned a new API, Aha~